# innocent looking xsl file acting evil

Tags: xml, html, xslt

I have collected this example from  .I am new to xsl and trying to understand how it works.The xsl here is written to sort out presidents by their party.Here i am providing two xsl file i wrote.One works(i mean show output) and another didn't work(that means show no output to the screen/i call it broken).But both the file didn't give any errors.Can any one explain to me why the broken xsl file  didn't show any output ?

xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='party.xslt'?>
<presidents  >
    <president>
        <number>1</number>
        <name>George Washington</name>
         <birthday>1732-02-22</birthday>
        <took_office>1789-04-30</took_office>
        <left_office>1797-03-04</left_office>
        <party>no party</party>
        <term>
            <term_number>1</term_number>
            <vice_president>John Adams</vice_president> 
        </term>
        <term>
            <term_number>2</term_number>
            <vice_president>John Adams</vice_president>
        </term>
    </president>

    <president>
        <number>2</number>
        <name>Mr.X</name>
         <birthday>1735-10-30</birthday>
        <took_office>1797-03-04</took_office>
        <left_office>1801-03-04</left_office>
        <party>Federalist</party>
        <term>
            <term_number>3</term_number>
            <vice_president>Thomas Jefferson</vice_president>
        </term>
    </president>
    <president>
        <number>2</number>
        <name>John Adams</name>
         <birthday>1735-10-30</birthday>
        <took_office>1797-03-04</took_office>
        <left_office>1801-03-04</left_office>
        <party>Democratic</party>
        <term>
            <term_number>3</term_number>
            <vice_president>Thomas Jefferson</vice_president>
        </term>
    </president>
</presidents>
```

xsl that didn't show output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'>
<xsl:template match='/'>

    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>sorting presidents</h1>
           <xsl:apply-templates select='presidents/president'>
                <xsl:sort select='party' data-type='text'/>
           </xsl:apply-templates>
      </body>
    </html>

</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match='presidents/president'>

    <xsl:apply-templates select='name'/>

</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match='name'>

     <span style='color:red;font-size:40px;'><xsl:value-of select='name'/></span><br/>

</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xsl that did show output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'>
<xsl:template match='/'>

    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>sorting presidents</h1>
           <xsl:apply-templates select='presidents/president'>
                <xsl:sort select='party' data-type='text'/>
           </xsl:apply-templates>
      </body>
    </html>

</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match='presidents/president'>

    <span style='color:red;font-size:40px;'><xsl:value-of select='name'/></span><br/>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing evil in here.

Have a look at the template matching *name* in the wrong XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match='name'>
  <span style='color:red;font-size:40px;'><xsl:value-of select='name'/></span>
  <br/>
```

By the use of the `<xsl:value-of select='name'/>`, you assume you have another `<name>` as child of the `<name>` currently matched. `<xsl:value-of select='.'/>` will produce the expected output.

By comparison with the good XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match='presidents/president'>
  <span style='color:red;font-size:40px;'><xsl:value-of select='name'/></span>
  <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

You are matching a `<president>`, and the `<xsl:value-of select='name'/>` instruction will successfully retrieve the `<name>` element as a child of `<president>`, which is  the right structure of your XML.

Comment: this is basic stuff.i should've remembered.Thanks a lot for your reply :)